# Working directory of nunit tests in Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, nunit

I've started trying to use the Test Explorer with the nunit test adapter. The unit tests that I'm running have some test files which are loaded from a test folder, the test folder contains test files which are specific to a particular project. Running nunit manually previously, I was able to specify the working directory for the test, but I can't see how I would do that when using the test explorer. So currently I have some unit tests failing because they're unable to find these test files.

I've tried using the project macro to define in the code where the test files will reside in relation to the project directory but that's given me more issues. I've tried setting the Project $(ProjectDir) macro as a Preprocessor definition as per [accessing-visual-studio-macros-from-source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888402/accessing-visual-studio-macros-from-source-code), however I'm using the compiler from visual studio 2008, so I either get `Warning   21  warning C4129: ')' : unrecognized character escape sequence' from`PROJECT_DIRECTORY="$(ProjectDir)"`because the backslashes in the directory structure from $(ProjectDir) or by doing PROJECT_DIRECTORY=LR"|($(ProjectDir))|" I get`C2065: 'LR' : undeclared identifier` because LR doesn't exist in C++ prior to C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is C++-CLI, you could [detect the assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly(v=vs.80).aspx) using something along the following lines and do a relative path from there:

```
Type^ type = SomeClassInYourAssembly::typeid;
Assembly^ containerAssembly = System::Reflection::Assembly::GetAssembly(type);
String^ pathTocontainerAssembly = containerAssembly->Location;
```